# Python multiprocesing and NLTK wordnet path similarity

Tags: python, nltk, python-multiprocessing, pool, wordnet

I am using multiprocessing pool to speed up the title extraction process on a text corpus. At one stage of the code, I am using wordnet path similarity module to determine the similarity of two words.

If i run my code sequentially i.e. without the use of multiprocessing pool, I get normal times in calculating this path similarity. However, when I use multiprocessing to process multiple documents simultaneously, I observe great time delays in computing this path similarity as compared to sequential.
Question: Does NLTK show any problems with multiprocessing module ?

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that the module in separate processes attempts to access the very same file with Wordnet data. This would result in dependence on GIL to access the file or OS-level file locks use. Both cases would explain the behaviour you are observing.

Comment: Thanks @sophros . This means that while calculating the path similarity, wordnet uses the file present on disk?
When I perform "from nltk.corpus import wordnet", does this not load the wordnet into the RAM?

Comment: I guess the phenomena you are explaining would only result in a one time delay when it loads the wordnet into the process whenever it is accessed. I am getting delays even after that.